# How I can convert this HTML code to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I have three different videos that I want to play at the same time.

```html
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <video id="a" preload>
        <source src="http://www.dendrosite.com/interactiu/paranoik.mp4" />
        <source src="http://www.dendrosite.com/interactiu/paranoik.webm" />
    </video>
</div>
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <video id="b" preload>
        <source src="http://www.dendrosite.com/interactiu/paranoik.mp4" />
        <source src="http://www.dendrosite.com/interactiu/paranoik.webm" />
    </video>
</div>
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <video id="c" preload>
        <source src="http://www.dendrosite.com/interactiu/paranoik.mp4" />
        <source src="http://www.dendrosite.com/interactiu/paranoik.webm" />
    </video>
</div>
```

To make this possible I create a button which calls the videos, goes correctly, but I think is more correctly do this with JavaScript.

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('a').pause(); document.getElementById('b').pause(); document.getElementById('c').pause()" ><span><img src="../imatges/pause.png"></span>
    Pause</button>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('a').play(); document.getElementById('b').play(); document.getElementById('c').play()"><img src="../imatges/play.png">
    Play</button>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('a').currentTime = 0; document.getElementById('b').currentTime = 0; document.getElementById('c').currentTime = 0"><img src="../imatges/back.png">Back to Beginning</button>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('a').currentTime += 5; document.getElementById('b').currentTime += 5; document.getElementById('c').currentTime += 5"><img src="../imatges/skip.png">
    Skip 5 Seconds</button>
```

The website is: http://www.dendrosite.com/interactiu/interactiu.html

Comment: If your button works, what's the problem?

Comment: @aleish76 - don't use inline events. Attach the onclick events via a JavaScript framework like jQuery, e.g. http://api.jquery.com/bind or http://api.jquery.com/live

Comment: I think you have some fundamental misunderstandings about [HTML and JavaScript](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=what+is+the+difference+between+html+and+javascript&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=4e0d51cc84241161&biw=1680&bih=883)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each button an id, then in a .js file, assign each an onclick handler that contains the same code.

New HTML:

```
<button id="pauseButton"><span><img src="../imatges/pause.png"></span>Pause</button>

<button id="playButton"><img src="../imatges/play.png">Play</button>

<button id="restartButton"><img src="../imatges/back.png">Back to Beginning</button>

<button id="skipButton"><img src="../imatges/skip.png">Skip 5 Seconds</button>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("pauseButton").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('a').pause();
    document.getElementById('b').pause();
    document.getElementById('c').pause();
};

document.getElementById("playButton").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('a').play();
    document.getElementById('b').play();
    document.getElementById('c').play();
};

document.getElementById("restartButton").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('a').currentTime = 0;
    document.getElementById('b').currentTime = 0;
    document.getElementById('c').currentTime = 0;
};

document.getElementById("skipButton").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('a').currentTime += 5;
    document.getElementById('b').currentTime += 5;
    document.getElementById('c').currentTime += 5;
};
```